# U-blox GNSS, what NMEA messages to enable just for time sync on linux?

Tags: gps, chrony

I'm recording raw output from an M8T on an SBC without an RTC, and would like to use GNSS for time sync.
Chrony won't use the GNSS unless I enable NEMA messages, but I don't know what are the minimum required to get a time sync.

I want to keep the NEMA messages at minimum as to keep the GNSS log as small as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you are asking a programmer question, or more a sysadmin question (so other sister sites are more relevant). Time to sync is very variable (also depending your antenna, and location of the satellites). But your question is much simpler: send the NMEA messages. The GPS unit will send NMEA time (and location) only when it has time (and location). (other messages may have just information on which satellites are in view, which are sync, and maybe some other information on the device)